# Rider ASP.Net MVC WebDeploy on MacOS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, rider

I'm trying to deploy my asp.net mvc web solution to a server. I'm using smarterasp.net. I received a PublishSettings xml file, and i have the FTP connection details.

With VisualStudio the process of starting the app somewhere else besides the local machine was pretty simple. I was using the xml file and the project compield himself on the server. Now Rider doesn't even want to connect via FTP. I managed to connect with FileZilla but my solution is not compield.

How can i manage to deploy my website with Rider on Mac ?

[image with ftp login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M94ts.png)

Comment: Web Publishing profile (the XML file) is currently only supported by Visual Studio (not sure if Visual Studio for Mac even supports it). You might use Help | Report a bug to let JetBrains know the issue, but personally I think they have so many in the plate right now, and such features would not come too soon.

Comment: Jeah, not supported right now. I also had to use VS